# How do I solve problems that occur when Akka cannot get heartbeat?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, heartbeat

When I work with Akka, I have problems if I do debug.They can't get heartbeat while they're debugging. Then they start not seeing each other anymore.

As far as I can tell, if he can't get a heartbeat after the next 10 seconds, he's out of the cluster and can't see each other anymore. I want to extend this period. For example, if you can't hearbeat for 5 minutes, then you should get out of the cluster.I'm looking for solutions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off auto-downing. That way the node you are debugging might get marked as unreachable, but it will never be removed from the cluster. (And as soon as you release it from being frozen the other nodes will mark it as reachable again.)

Comment: Thank you. I will try :)